# edit.GoToDefinition (F12) unsetable with Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I have resharper installed and have tried this on both base keyboard configurations you can set resharper to (Visual Studio, and Resharper.) If I go to **tools/options/keyboard** and assign the keyboard **F12** to  **edit.GoToDefinition** and save it won't work. I love resharper but this is the command I use the most and it's killing me that it can't be set. Any ideas how to get around this? I've tried:

1) **Resetting all keyboard settings from internal/export options and re-configuring**

2) **Switching VS Versions**

3) **Reinstalling Resharper**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Visual Studio's functionality back by selecting "override Visual Studio refactorings" in ReSharper → Options → Keyboard & Menus.

There are some features that ReSharper can't override simply by changing a key mapping - notably, commands invoked from menu items, such as Visual Studio's own refactorings, and "go to definition" on the context menu. Instead, ReSharper installs a command target handler, a Visual Studio extension point that allows extensions to be notified when a command is invoked, and provide an alternative implementation (for example, the same "rename" refactoring command can have different implementations for different supporting languages). ReSharper overrides Visual Studio's implementations to provide its own functionality.